# Creating rest endpoints for consumer and producers

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to write rest endpoints for user and his services. Not sure for the below use case it should be in User or Service controller.

The below examples will find the service in which the "userId" is a consumer or producer

```
http://localhost/user/{userId}/consumer/services
http://localhost/user/{userId}/producer/services
```

or

```
http://localhost/service/consumer/user/{userId}
http://localhost/service/producer/user/{userId}
```

The first example makes more sense to me, any suggestions and a good approach?

Answer (score 1):

If you ask me, I would recommend the 1st approach. But having said that, I would route the requests to the Controllers this way

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/user")
public class UserController{
 // write code for User API
}

@RequestMapping(path = "/user/{userId}/consumer")
public class ConsumerController{
  // write code for Services API
}

@RequestMapping(path = "/user/{userId}/producer")
public class ProducerController{
 // write code for Services API
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Neither one. As long as the user is not the subject of action (entity on which action is performed), user info is the metadata which you can (and should) derive from the Authentication principal rather than what's coming on the URL

Comment: Can you explain with some examples?

Answer (score 0):

I am planning to use the following as it seems more appropriate.

```
http://localhost/service?userId={userId}&userType={userType}
```

userType= CONSUMER OR PRODUCER

The above will return the services where the userId is a CONSUMER or PRODUCER of the service.